# Drag and drop images into word not working

Tags: microsoft-word, images, drag-and-drop

Using MS Word 2000, I'm no longer able to drag and drop images into MS word from the local filesystem (or from images on the web).   We recently reinstalled XP and SP3, so I'm not sure if this is a new security feature (?).

Currently, the system lists the filename when I drag an image into Word.  It used to just show the actual image.

How can I set up Word to let me drag and drop images again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why use such an old version of Word?

Next, in Word's `Options dialog / Edit tab`, make sure `Drag-and-drop text editing` and `Use smart cut and paste` are selected:

[image]

Finally, after you drag and drop an image if you see just an icon and filename, try pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.